# MvvmCross (iOS) can't bind property in UILabel derived class

Tags: mvvmcross

MvvmCross noob here. Does anyone know why I can't bind a property in a UILabel derived class?

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
set.Bind(_serverValue).For(p => p.Text).To(vm => vm.ServerListSelectedItem);
set.Bind(_serverValue).For(p => p.Visible).To(vm => vm.IsServerListAvailable);
set.Apply();

private class ServerValue : UILabel
{
  public bool Visible
  {
    get { return !Hidden; }
    set { Hidden = !value; LoginView.LayoutControls(); }
  }
}
```

The text gets updated but the Visible property never does. Should I even expect that this should work?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvvmCross uses Reflection - and Reflection is subject to .Net security rules.

Try making your control `public` rather than `private` to see if that helps -

```
 public class ServerValue : UILabel ...`
```

---

Beyond that, there is also a registered custom binding for `Visible` in MvvmCross by default - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/MvxTouchBindingBuilder.cs#L45

```
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<UIView>("Visible",
                                                    view =>
                                                    new MvxUIViewVisibleTargetBinding(view));
```

You may find that this conflicts with (and hides) your `Visible` property - custom bindings are checked before Reflection - so you may need to choose a different property name.

For more on binding to custom properties and more on custom bindings see N=19 and N=28 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.com

Comment: It seems to have been the Visible property conflicting. I've renamed the property. Thanks.